# QT compile error

Tags: c++, qt

I was playing with a tiny QT 5.5.1 app under windows/mingw. Suddenly it stopped compile with a weird error like on the screenshot.

I tried to clean all, rebuild, run qmake. No results.

How to get rid of it?

[image: q]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, to all downvoters, I've solved it by myself.

The problem was that QT was not able to create Debug directory where it should put compiled files. Don't ask me why.

Thus what we have. No output directory -> no main.o created -> this weird compile error.

Comment: That's where IDE's are surely inferior to a command-line setup of e.g. cmake + editor + gdb. They add abstraction that sometimes gets in the way.